# How to pass enumarate (or list) to SQLite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to do something like:

```
import sqlite3 as db

db.paramstyle = 'pyformat'
weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"]
c = db.connect(database="tvprogram")
cu = c.cursor()
cu.executemany("INSERT INTO wd VALUES (%s, %s);", enumerate(weekdays))
```

But I have an error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany), you should use `?` instead of `%s`. Thus:

```
cu.executemany("INSERT INTO wd VALUES (?, ?);", enumerate(weekdays))
```

should work.